# Не работает видео html

Tags: html, видео

Пытаюсь добавить видео на задний фон страницы, но оно не запускается.

```
<video autoplay controls  src="https://www.division.global/admin/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/JOB_Preview-Welcome_Justyna-Obasi.mp4" ></video>
```

Оно запускается только если нажать плей - а по атрибут autoplay оно не хочет работать

Comment: autoplay="autoplay"

Comment: @Rudi не помогло, пытался

Answer (score 0):

autoplay работает только с параметром muted